No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it in .NET MAUI application (using Windows machine)
I am trying to imitate online payment using Stripe payment gateway in .NET MAUI application. Server is represented by web API Asp.NET Core app. It works well when I use .NET MAUI Blazor app as frontend app, but I get a connection error when I am trying to implement it in a simple MAUI app. This is how the code looks like:
private async void OnPayClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Order order = new Order("today",1,1,1,true,10,false);
    var response = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{DevApiBaseAddress}/checkout", order); //error

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var checkoutOrderResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckoutOrderResponse>(responseBody);

    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("checkout", checkoutOrderResponse.PubKey, checkoutOrderResponse.SessionId);
}

Maybe I should add some additional settings concerning HTTP connection?
There were a few answers suggesting that it was Firewall block, but I added inbound permissions per specified local ports. I also made sure that other processes didn't take these ports.
So, my question is why it is working when I use Blazor but not .NET MAUI app?
In this controller connection with Stripe must be done.
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class CheckoutController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    private static string s_wasmClientURL = string.Empty;

    public CheckoutController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CheckoutOrder([FromBody] Order product, [FromServices] IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        var referer = Request.Headers.Referer;
        s_wasmClientURL = referer[0];

        // Build the URL to which the customer will be redirected after paying.
        var server = sp.GetRequiredService<IServer>();

        var serverAddressesFeature = server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();

        string? thisApiUrl = null;

        if (serverAddressesFeature is not null)
        {
            thisApiUrl = serverAddressesFeature.Addresses.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if (thisApiUrl is not null)
        {
            var sessionId = await CheckOut(product, thisApiUrl);
            var pubKey = _configuration["Stripe:PubKey"];

            var checkoutOrderResponse = new CheckoutOrderResponse()
            {
                SessionId = sessionId,
                PubKey = pubKey
            };

            return Ok(checkoutOrderResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }

    [NonAction]
    public async Task<string> CheckOut(Order product, string thisApiUrl)
    {
        // Create a payment flow from the items in the cart.
        // Gets sent to Stripe API.
        var options = new SessionCreateOptions
        {
            // Stripe calls the URLs below when certain checkout events happen such as success and failure.
            SuccessUrl = $"{thisApiUrl}/checkout/success?sessionId=" + "{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}", // Customer paid.
            CancelUrl = s_wasmClientURL + "failed",  // Checkout cancelled.
            PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> // Only card available in test mode?
            {
                "card"
            },
            LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
            {
                new()
                {
                    PriceData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
                    {
                        UnitAmount = (long)product.Price, // Price is in USD cents.
                        Currency = "USD",
                        ProductData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
                        {
                            Name = product.BaseRequestId.ToString(),
                        },
                    },
                    Quantity = 1,
                },
            },
            Mode = "payment" // One-time payment. Stripe supports recurring 'subscription' payments.
        };

        var service = new SessionService();
        var session = await service.CreateAsync(options);

        return session.Id;
    }

    [HttpGet("success")]
    // Automatic query parameter handling from ASP.NET.
    // Example URL: https://localhost:7051/checkout/success?sessionId=si_123123123123
    public ActionResult CheckoutSuccess(string sessionId)
    {
        var sessionService = new SessionService();
        var session = sessionService.Get(sessionId);

        // Here you can save order and customer details to your database.
        var total = session.AmountTotal.Value;
        var customerEmail = session.CustomerDetails.Email;

        return Redirect(s_wasmClientURL + "success");
    }
}

Finally, Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Stripe;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = builder.Configuration["Stripe:SecretKey"];

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Important detail!
When the target platform is Android, connection is successfully established. But in case of using Windows machine, it doesn't work. It was suggested to modify server's configuration to allow remote access, but I still don't understand what exactly I need to modify. Platform version is 10, Visual Studio version is 17.7.6.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78502406/3392605

is your web server setup to accept remote connections?

@MustafaMutasim Thanks for interest, but I am running my app on Windows machine and I didn't even add android sdk to the project. I am not sure Windows needs these settings.

@Jason Thanks for interest, unfortunately, I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. I'll update my question with Program.cs code. I didn't modify it a lot, so I think that I simply don't know what I could add here.

I assume your service is running under IIS Express or whatever they call the VS dev server these days.  These are typically setup by default to only allow connections from local clients.  Mobile devices, even if they are emulators running on the same machine, will appear to be remote clients.  So you need to modify your sever config to allow remote access.

@CMlllll Welcome. I added inbound permissions per specified local ports disable the firewall\Antivirus temporarily on all zones private, domain and public to confirm it.

Dear @Jason, I can confirm that, there is no extra settings are required on IIS, I've tested my APIs from IOS\Android\Windows MAUI(.net6\7\8) Windows Server 2012.

IIS is not the same as IIS Express or the dev web server that comes with VS

@Jason I found one answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112820/net-core-ocelot-a-public-method-named-configuredevelopment-or-configure-cou
I tried to add this code, but result is same. I can be mistaken, but can you suggest what I should concretly add to my code?

@MustafaMutasim No antivirus is activated while running my app. Another problem is that it is running when target platform is Android. So, I need to modify configuration for Windows platform, the problem is that I don't know how. I tried to implement code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112820/net-core-ocelot-a-public-method-named-configuredevelopment-or-configure-cou but it didn't help

Please update your question with that info [it is running when target platform is Android] to let answers focus on the visual studio windows platform, and share your targeting platform[6\7\8] and visual studio version if you are not uptodate
